# Centering a dropdown menu below parent menu with CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have an issue with a dropdown menu that is appearing too much to the left of its parent menu.

- Here: http://dev.gratefulhearttherapy.org/
- Hover the menu 'Services'
  in the nav bar
- See the dropdown menu appearing too much to the left (compare with the menu 'About Us')

I'm a bit confused with the positioning since the CSS for the nav menu wasn't done by myself for the most part. I would really appreciate some help with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a test page that just includes the menubar? It'd be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: @Charlie, I just set up this one if that helps: http://dev.gratefulhearttherapy.org/test

Comment: Could you just include the menubar? No other page elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set position: relative on the top menu container and remove the left: 142px on the sub-container, you'll be aligned left.

```
.custom ul.mega-menu li {
    position: relative
}
.custom ul.mega-menu li .sub-container {
    left: 0
}
```

Comment: I copied your lines at the end of my CSS file and it doesn't work as expected. The dropdown for 'Services' shows up below 'Therapists', and the dropdown for 'About US' shows up way out at the right of the nav bar. You can maybe try it with the Chrome Inspector.
Not sure if it comes from your code or if I didn't implement it right.

Comment: That's because some rules are in your HTML and override CSS rules.
You should remove the 'left: 142px' rule from the HTML code.

Comment: It works, thanks! I had to override the HTML rule by using !important in my CSS file though. The rule seems to be dynamically generated by the 'Mega Menu' plugin that I use (and what is a 142px value for you is a 126px value for me), so I don't know how to disable it at the source.